# Converting a list of list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have data file, which looks like this,

```
["Arts & Entertainment", "Arts & Entertainment / Animation & Comics", "Arts & Entertainment / Books & Literature", "Arts & Entertainment / Celebrity/Gossip", "Arts & Entertainment / Fine Art", "Arts & Entertainment / Humor", "Arts & Entertainment / Movies", "Arts & Entertainment / Movies / Action", "Arts & Entertainment / Movies / Comedy", "Arts & Entertainment / Movies / Documentary", "Arts & Entertainment / Movies / Drama", "Arts & Entertainment / Movies / Horror", "Arts & Entertainment / Music", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Alternative Music", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Blues", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Christian Music", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Classic Rock", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Classical Music", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Country Music", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Electronic Dance Music", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Heavy Metal", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Pop Music", "Arts & Entertainment / Music / Rap", "Arts & Entertainment / Radio Stations", "Arts & Entertainment / Television", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / Game Show", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / Kids", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / News", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / Reality", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / Science", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / Sitcom", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / Soap Opera", "Arts & Entertainment / Television / Talk Show", "Autos", "Autos / 4-Wheel Drive/SUVs", "Autos / Buying/Selling Cars", "Autos / Certified Pre-Owned", "Autos / Convertible", "Autos / Coupe", "Autos / Crossover", "Autos / Diesel", "Autos / Electric Vehicles", "Autos / Hatchback", "Autos / Hybrid", "Autos / Luxury", "Autos / Maintenance", "Autos / Maintenance / Parts", "Autos / Maintenance / Repair", "Autos / MiniVan", "Autos / Motorcycles", "Autos / Off-Road Vehicles", "Autos / Road-Side Assistance", "Autos / Sedan", "Autos / Trucks", "Autos / Trucks / Pickup", "Autos / Vintage Cars", "Autos / Wagon", "Business & Industry", "Business & Industry / Advertising", "Business & Industry / Agriculture", "Business & Industry / Biotech/Biomedical", "Business & Industry / Business Software", "Business & Industry / Construction", "Business & Industry / Construction / Composites & Plastics", "Business & Industry / Forestry", "Business & Industry / Government", "Business & Industry / Green Solutions", "Business & Industry / Human Resources", "Business & Industry / Logistics", "Business & Industry / Marketing", "Business & Industry / Metals", "Business & Industry / Non-Profit Organizations", "Business & Industry / Power Industry", "Business & Industry / Public Services", "Business & Industry / Public Services / Emergency Services", "Business & Industry / Public Services / Waste Management", "Business & Industry / Purchasing", "Business & Industry / Retail Industry", "Business & Industry / Small Business", "Business & Industry / Telecom", "Career", "Career / Career Planning", "Career / Job Search", "Career / Job Search / Resume Writing/Advice", "Career / Telecommuting", "Career / U.S. Military", "Education", "Education / Business School", "Education / College Education", "Education / College Education / Admissions", "Education / College Education / College Life", "Education / Continuing Education", "Education / Distance Learning", "Education / Financial Aid", "Education / Financial Aid / Scholarships", "Education / Graduate School", "Education / Homeschooling", "Education / Language Learning", "Education / Language Learning / English as a 2nd Language", "Education / Primary Education", "Education / Secondary Education", "Education / Special Education", "Finance & Money", "Finance & Money / Credit/Debt & Loans", "Finance & Money / Day Trading", "Finance & Money / Exchange Traded Funds", "Finance & Money / Financial News", "Finance & Money / Financial Planning", "Finance & Money / Financial Planning / Retirement Planning", "Finance & Money / Financial Planning / Tax Planning", "Finance & Money / Foreign Exchange Trading", "Finance & Money / Hedge Fund", "Finance & Money / Insurance", "Finance & Money / Investing", "Finance & Money / Mutual Funds", "Finance & Money / Options", "Finance & Money / Stocks", "Food & Drink", "Food & Drink / Barbecues & Grilling", "Food & Drink / Beverages", "Food & Drink / Beverages / Cocktails/Beer", "Food & Drink / Beverages / Coffee/Tea", "Food & Drink / Beverages / Wine", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific / American Cusine", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific / Cajun/Creole", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific / Chinese Cuisine", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific / French Cuisine", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific / Italian Food", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific / Japanese Food", "Food & Drink / Cuisine-Specific / Mexican Cuisine", "Food & Drink / Desserts & Baking", "Food & Drink / Health/LowFat Cooking", "Food & Drink / Organic Food", "Food & Drink / Vegetarian", "Health & Fitness", "Health & Fitness / A.D.D.", "Health & Fitness / AIDS/HIV", "Health & Fitness / Allergies", "Health & Fitness / Alternative Medicine", "Health & Fitness / Alzheimer\\'s Disease", "Health & Fitness / Arthritis", "Health & Fitness / Asthma", "Health & Fitness / Autism/PDD", "Health & Fitness / Bipolar Disorder", "Health & Fitness / Brain Tumor", "Health & Fitness / Cancer", "Health & Fitness / Cancer / Breast Cancer", "Health & Fitness / Cancer / Lung Cancer", "Health & Fitness / Cancer / Prostate Cancer", "Health & Fitness / Cholesterol", "Health & Fitness / Chronic Fatigue Syndrome", "Health & Fitness / Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease", "Health & Fitness / Chronic Pain", "Health & Fitness / Cold & Flu", "Health & Fitness / Deafness", "Health & Fitness / Dental Care", "Health & Fitness / Depression", "Health & Fitness / Dermatology", "Health & Fitness / Diabetes", "Health & Fitness / Epilepsy", "Health & Fitness / Exercise", "Health & Fitness / GERD/Acid Reflux", "Health & Fitness / Headaches/Migraines", "Health & Fitness / Heart Disease", "Health & Fitness / Heart Disease / Women\\'s Heart Disease", "Health & Fitness / Hepatitis", "Health & Fitness / Herbs for Health", "Health & Fitness / Holistic Healing", "Health & Fitness / Hypertension", "Health & Fitness / IBS/Crohn\\'s Disease", "Health & Fitness / Incest/Abuse Support", "Health & Fitness / Incontinence", "Health & Fitness / Infertility", "Health & Fitness / Men\\'s Health", "Health & Fitness / Nursing", "Health & Fitness / Nutrition", "Health & Fitness / Orthopedics", "Health & Fitness / Orthopedics / Sports Medicine", "Health & Fitness / Panic/Anxiety Disorders", "Health & Fitness / Pediatrics", "Health & Fitness / Pharmaceutical", "Health & Fitness / Physical Therapy", "Health & Fitness / Psychology/Psychiatry", "Health & Fitness / Senior Health", "Health & Fitness / Sexuality", "Health & Fitness / Sleep Disorders", "Health & Fitness / Smoking Cessation", "Health & Fitness / Substance Abuse", "Health & Fitness / Substance Abuse / Alcoholism", "Health & Fitness / Thyroid Disease", "Health & Fitness / Weight Loss", "Health & Fitness / Women\\'s Health", "Hobbies & Games", "Hobbies & Games / Arts & Crafts", "Hobbies & Games / Arts & Crafts / Beadwork", "Hobbies & Games / Arts & Crafts / Drawing/Sketching", "Hobbies & Games / Arts & Crafts / Needlework", "Hobbies & Games / Arts & Crafts / Painting", "Hobbies & Games / Arts & Crafts / Photography", "Hobbies & Games / Arts & Crafts / Woodworking", "Hobbies & Games / Astrology", "Hobbies & Games / Birdwatching", "Hobbies & Games / BoardGames/Puzzles", "Hobbies & Games / Candle & Soap Making", "Hobbies & Games / Card Games", "Hobbies & Games / Chess", "Hobbies & Games / Cigars", "Hobbies & Games / Collecting", "Hobbies & Games / Collecting / Antiques", "Hobbies & Games / Collecting / Book Collecting", "Hobbies & Games / Collecting / Miniatures", "Hobbies & Games / Collecting / Stamps & Coins", "Hobbies & Games / Creative Writing", "Hobbies & Games / Getting Published", "Hobbies & Games / Home Recording", "Hobbies & Games / Inventors & Patents", "Hobbies & Games / Learning a Musical Instrument", "Hobbies & Games / Learning a Musical Instrument / Guitar", "Hobbies & Games / Magic & Illusion", "Hobbies & Games / Paranormal Phenomena", "Hobbies & Games / Sci-Fi & Fantasy", "Hobbies & Games / Video Games", "Hobbies & Games / Video Games / Nintendo", "Hobbies & Games / Video Games / PSP", "Hobbies & Games / Video Games / Playstation", "Hobbies & Games / Video Games / RPG", "Hobbies & Games / Video Games / Racing", "Hobbies & Games / Video Games / X-Box", "Home & Garden", "Home & Garden / Appliances", "Home & Garden / Environmental Safety", "Home & Garden / Gardening/Landscaping", "Home & Garden / Home Repair", "Home & Garden / Interior Decorating", "News & Current Affairs", "News & Current Affairs / Law & Politics", "News & Current Affairs / Law & Politics / Immigration", "News & Current Affairs / Law & Politics / Legal Issues", "News & Current Affairs / Law & Politics / U.S. Government Resources", "Parenting & Family", "Parenting & Family / Adoption", "Parenting & Family / Babies & Toddlers", "Parenting & Family / Daycare/Pre-School", "Parenting & Family / Parenting Children", "Parenting & Family / Parenting Teens", "Parenting & Family / Pregnancy", "Parenting & Family / Special Needs Kids", "Pets", "Pets / Aquariums", "Pets / Cats", "Pets / Dogs", "Pets / Veterinary Medicine", "Real Estate", "Real Estate / Apartments", "Real Estate / Architecture", "Real Estate / Buying/Selling Homes", "Religion", "Religion / Alternative Religions", "Religion / Atheism/Agnosticism", "Religion / Buddhism", "Religion / Catholicism", "Religion / Christianity", "Religion / Hinduism", "Religion / Islam", "Religion / Judaism", "Religion / Latter-Day Saints", "Religion / Pagan/Wiccan", "Science", "Science / Astronomy", "Science / Biology", "Science / Chemistry", "Science / Geology", "Science / Physics", "Sensitive Content", "Sensitive Content / Gambling", "Sensitive Content / Gambling / Sports Gambling", "Society", "Society / Dating", "Society / Divorce", "Society / Gay Life", "Society / Marriage", "Society / Senior Living", "Society / Weddings", "Sports & Recreation", "Sports & Recreation / Auto Racing", "Sports & Recreation / Auto Racing / NASCAR Racing", "Sports & Recreation / Baseball", "Sports & Recreation / Basketball", "Sports & Recreation / Bicycling", "Sports & Recreation / Bicycling / Mountain Biking", "Sports & Recreation / Bodybuilding", "Sports & Recreation / Boxing", "Sports & Recreation / Canoeing/Kayaking", "Sports & Recreation / Cheerleading", "Sports & Recreation / Climbing", "Sports & Recreation / College Sports", "Sports & Recreation / Cricket", "Sports & Recreation / Figure Skating", "Sports & Recreation / Fishing", "Sports & Recreation / Fishing / Fly Fishing", "Sports & Recreation / Fishing / Freshwater Fishing", "Sports & Recreation / Fishing / Game & Fish", "Sports & Recreation / Fishing / Saltwater Fishing", "Sports & Recreation / Football", "Sports & Recreation / Golf", "Sports & Recreation / Horses", "Sports & Recreation / Horses / Horse Racing", "Sports & Recreation / Hunting/Shooting", "Sports & Recreation / Ice Hockey", "Sports & Recreation / Inline Skating", "Sports & Recreation / Martial Arts", "Sports & Recreation / Olympics", "Sports & Recreation / Paintball", "Sports & Recreation / Rodeo", "Sports & Recreation / Rugby", "Sports & Recreation / Running/Walking", "Sports & Recreation / Sailing", "Sports & Recreation / Scuba Diving", "Sports & Recreation / Skateboarding", "Sports & Recreation / Skiing", "Sports & Recreation / Snowboarding", "Sports & Recreation / Soccer", "Sports & Recreation / Surfing/Bodyboarding", "Sports & Recreation / Swimming", "Sports & Recreation / Table Tennis/Ping-Pong", "Sports & Recreation / Tennis", "Sports & Recreation / Volleyball", "Sports & Recreation / Waterski/Wakeboard", "Sports & Recreation / Yachting", "Style & Fashion", "Style & Fashion / Body Art", "Style & Fashion / Cosmetics", "Style & Fashion / Fashion", "Style & Fashion / Jewelry", "Technology & Computing", "Technology & Computing / Cameras & Camcorders", "Technology & Computing / Cell Phones", "Technology & Computing / Computer Certification", "Technology & Computing / Computer Networking", "Technology & Computing / Computer Peripherals", "Technology & Computing / Computer Security", "Technology & Computing / Computer Security / Antivirus Software", "Technology & Computing / Computer Security / Network Security", "Technology & Computing / Databases", "Technology & Computing / Graphics", "Technology & Computing / Graphics / 3-D Graphics", "Technology & Computing / Graphics / Animation", "Technology & Computing / Graphics / Desktop Publishing", "Technology & Computing / Graphics / Desktop Video", "Technology & Computing / Graphics / Web Design/HTML", "Technology & Computing / Home Theater Systems", "Technology & Computing / Operating Systems", "Technology & Computing / Operating Systems / Linux", "Technology & Computing / Operating Systems / Mac OS", "Technology & Computing / Operating Systems / Unix", "Technology & Computing / Operating Systems / Windows", "Technology & Computing / Portable Device", "Technology & Computing / Programming", "Technology & Computing / Programming / C/C++", "Technology & Computing / Programming / Java", "Technology & Computing / Programming / JavaScript", "Technology & Computing / Programming / Visual Basic", "Travel", "Travel / Adventure Travel", "Travel / Africa", "Travel / Air Travel", "Travel / Asia", "Travel / Asia / Japan", "Travel / Australia & New Zealand", "Travel / Bed & Breakfasts", "Travel / Budget Travel", "Travel / Business Travel", "Travel / Camping", "Travel / Canada", "Travel / Caribbean", "Travel / Cruises", "Travel / Europe", "Travel / Europe / Eastern Europe", "Travel / Europe / France", "Travel / Europe / Greece", "Travel / Europe / Italy", "Travel / Europe / United Kingdom", "Travel / Honeymoons/Getaways", "Travel / Hotels", "Travel / Mexico & Central America", "Travel / National Parks", "Travel / South America", "Travel / Spas", "Travel / Theme Parks", "Travel / United States", "Travel / United States / California", "Travel / United States / Florida", "Travel / United States / Hawaii", "Travel / United States / Las Vegas, Nevada", "Travel / United States / Manhattan, New York", "Travel / United States / New England", "Travel / United States / Texas", "Travel / Weather"]
```

I clean up the data file and I split it, so that it looks something like this,

```
['Arts & Entertainment']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Animation & Comics']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Books & Literature']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Celebrity Gossip']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Fine Art']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Humor']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Movies']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Movies', 'Action']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Movies', 'Comedy']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Movies', 'Documentary']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Movies', 'Drama']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Movies', 'Horror']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Alternative Music']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Blues']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Christian Music']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Classic Rock']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Classical Music']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Country Music']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Electronic Dance Music']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Heavy Metal']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Pop Music']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Music', 'Rap']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Radio Stations']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Game Show']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Kids']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'News']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Reality']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Science']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Sitcom']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Soap Opera']
['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Talk Show']...
```

Now, I'm trying to convert the the list objects into a dictionary that looks like this,

```
{
    "Arts & Entertainment": {
        "Animation & Comics": {}, 
        "Books & Literature": {}, 
        "Celebrity Gossip": {}, 
        "Fine Art": {}, 
        "Humor": {}, 
        "Movies": {
            "Horror": {},
            "Action": {},
            "Comedy": {}, ...
        }, ...
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to not override my subcategories, In the example above, the Movies sub key has three categories with it, however when I run my code, which is below it just has the key of "Horror" in it and that's because Horror is the last element in the last element of the last list in that category.
Example of what I'm getting:

```
{
    "Arts & Entertainment": {
        "Animation & Comics": {}, 
        "Books & Literature": {}, 
        "Celebrity Gossip": {}, 
        "Fine Art": {}, 
        "Humor": {}, 
        "Movies": {
            "Horror": {} # notice there are no other categories in the movies section
        }, ...
}
```

Code I've tried:

```
def cleanup_contextweb():
  contextweb_file_path = directory_path + raw_file_names[1]
  tree = {}
  with open(contextweb_file_path, 'r') as contextweb_file:
    cats = contextweb_file.read().replace('Manhattan, New York', 'Manhattan New York').replace('Las Vegas, Nevada', 'Las Vegas Nevada').replace('Celebrity/Gossip', 'Celebrity Gossip').replace('Atheism/Agnosticism', 'Atheism Agnosticism').replace('Pagan/Wiccan', 'Pagan Wiccan').split(',')
    #cats = re.sub(r'"|\[|\]', '', cats)
    cats = [map(str.strip, re.sub(r'"|\[|\]', '', cat).split('/')) for cat in cats]
    cats = sorted(cats)
    for cat in cats:
      if len(cat) == 1:
        tree[cat[0]] = {}
      elif len(cat) == 2:
        tree[cat[0]][cat[1]] = {}
      elif len(cat) == 3:
        tree[cat[0]][cat[1]] = {}
        tree[cat[0]][cat[1]][cat[2]] = {}
      elif len(cat) == 4:
        tree[cat[0]][cat[1]] = {}
        tree[cat[0]][cat[1]][cat[2]] = {}
        tree[cat[0]][cat[1]][cat[2]][cat[3]] = {}
  with open(directory_path + 'cleaned_' + raw_file_names[1], 'w') as contextweb_file_out:
    json.dump(tree, contextweb_file_out, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

  return json.dumps(tree, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

As you'll see I'm trying to build the dictionary I know how deep (how many keys I need) I am based on the length of the list passed in. Other things, I've tried, but erased, include, sorting the list of lists (`cats`) by the length of the sub list and reversing it, so that all list with 4 elements would be iterated on first. I thought I could build the keys up that way because the key would exist for lower levels. That didn't really help.

Comment: you are replacing the value of each key with an empty dict every time, or in the case of `tree[cat[0]][cat[1]] = {cat[2] : {}}`, a dict with only this one key. you should instead be adding a new key if they key already exists, and a new dict if it doesnt.

Comment: Have you tried recursion?  Take all elements with the same first element.  Chop off the first element, call self with the shortened lists.  This returns a dictionary of those elements.  When you have only one element, return it as a the key to an empty dictionary.

Is that clear enough to implement?

Comment: @RNar Oh yeah, I'm sorry about that that was a typo, me playing around with the code, removing it yields the same result though.

Comment: @Prune no i haven't tried recursion, mostly because I have issues implementing recursive methods, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Also take a look at the .setdefault() method for a dictionary. It might fix your logic and simplify your code. Especially, in combination with recursion.

Comment: that is because you are still replacing every parent dictionary with an empty dictionary before setting the new key. I assume you did this to ensure to prevent trying to call on a dictionary that hasnt been set. however, if your data file is exactly as you show it, that means that the parent dict should always havea line before any of its children so you can take those out

Comment: @R Nar that was part of the reason why I did that and yes the data file is exactly how I posted it. However when I don't set the keys the keys the way I did I get the key doesn't exist error, that's why I thought sorting the list of list by length of list and reversing it would fix that, because then all the bottom level keys would exist and I would just work backwards.

Comment: are you sure? because it seemed to work for me using your code but without those definitions of empty dicts ie for len ==3/4, just use the last lines in each elif block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what it looks like with recursion:

```
data = [
    ['Arts & Entertainment'],
    ['Arts & Entertainment', 'Animation & Comics'],
    ...,      # full data list elided for readability
    ['Arts & Entertainment', 'Television', 'Talk Show']
]

def classify(in_list):
    sub_dict = {}

    label_set = set([category[0] for category in in_list])
    for label in label_set:
        # print label
        sub_category = [sub[1:] for sub in in_list if sub[0] == label and len(sub) > 1]
        # print sub_category
        sub_dict[label] = classify(sub_category)

    return sub_dict


print classify(data)
```

Output (which I did not format for readability):

```
{'Arts & Entertainment': {'Celebrity Gossip': {}, 'Humor': {}, 'Television': {'Game Show': {}, 'Kids': {}, 'Science': {}, 'Talk Show': {}, 'Sitcom': {}, 'Reality': {}, 'Soap Opera': {}, 'News': {}}, 'Animation & Comics': {}, 'Movies': {'Action': {}, 'Drama': {}, 'Horror': {}, 'Comedy': {}, 'Documentary': {}}, 'Radio Stations': {}, 'Music': {'Alternative Music': {}, 'Christian Music': {}, 'Electronic Dance Music': {}, 'Pop Music': {}, 'Country Music': {}, 'Classical Music': {}, 'Rap': {}, 'Heavy Metal': {}, 'Blues': {}, 'Classic Rock': {}}, 'Fine Art': {}, 'Books & Literature': {}}}
```

Comment: I hope this is straightforward enough for you to understand.  I left in my tracking print statements, in case those help you follow the logic.

Comment: Yes thank you very much, it is easy to read and therefore easy to study as well, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, a for-loop can produce quite a nice solution too:

```
>>> data
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 's', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
>>> tree = {}
>>> for cats in data:
...      curtree = tree
...      for c in cats:
...          curtree = curtree.setdefault(c, {})
... 
>>> tree
{'a': {'s': {'d': {}}, 'b': {'c': {'d': {'e': {}}}}}}
```

The `.setdefault()` method assures, that sub-dictionary is added if and only if key (category) has not existed before.

The `curtree` starts from base dictionary `tree` and traverses / builds the tree using the categories.

Comment: I really liked you're solution as well, I choice the other one because it gives me practice with recursion, which is a weak point of mine.

Comment: Thanks.  I voted this one up: when the loop solution is as straightforward as the recursive one, it's best practice to use the loop.